# Python Pandas: Find Sum of Column Based on Value of Two other Columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

While iterating through the `variableA` column, I want to generate a new column that is the sum of `values` whenever a row in *either* `variableA` or `variableB` equals the current row values of `variableA`. Example data:

```
    values    variableA  variableB
  0  134       1             3
  1  12        2             6
  2  43        1             2
  3  54        3             1
  4  16        2             7
```

I can select the sum of `values` whenever `variableA` matches the current row of `variableA` using:

```
df.groupby('variableA')['values'].transform('sum')
```

but selecting the sum of `values` whenever `variableB` matches the current row of `variableA` eludes me. I tried `.loc` but it doesn't seem to play well with `.groupby`. The expected output would be as follows:

```
    values    variableA  variableB  result
  0  134       1             3      231
  1  12        2             6      71
  2  43        1             2      231
  3  54        3             1      188
  4  16        2             7      71
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized approach with numpy broadcasting

```
vars = df[['variableA', 'variableB']].values
matches = (vars[:, None] == vars[:, [0]]).any(-1)

df.assign(result=df['values'].values @ matches)  # @ operator with python 3
# use this for use python 2
# df.assign(result=df['values'].values.dot(matches))
```

[image]

---

***time testing***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always use `.apply`, but  be warned: it can be slow:

```
>>> df
   values  variableA  variableB
0     134          1          3
1      12          2          6
2      43          1          2
3      54          3          1
4      16          2          7
>>> df.apply(lambda S: df.loc[(df.variableA == S.variableA) | (df.variableB == S.variableA), 'values'].sum(), axis=1)
0    231
1     71
2    231
3    188
4     71
dtype: int64
```

Of course, you would have to assign it...

```
>>> df['result'] = df.apply(lambda S: df.loc[(df.variableA == S.variableA) | (df.variableB == S.variableA), 'values'].sum(), axis=1)
>>> df
   values  variableA  variableB  result
0     134          1          3     231
1      12          2          6      71
2      43          1          2     231
3      54          3          1     188
4      16          2          7      71
```